# How to send Date object through Moshi JSON serializer?

Tags: android, moshi

I have to send `Date` object to server through API (actually, `Date` is object that server is expecting). I want to use Moshi, but I can't figure out how to use Custom Adapter to make it happen. Anyone?

Comment: `Date` is not something that is specified in JSON. So your server can't be expecting a Date object. It is expecting a certain representation of a Date, be it a string with a certain format, or a timestamp, or a complex structure. You need to start by figuring what format you are supposed to send, first.

Comment: I'm supposed to send JSON

Comment: but `Date` has no meaning in the context of `JSON`. So that does not make sense. You have to figure out what format your server is expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Add a dependency on the moshi-adapters package:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
  <artifactId>moshi-adapters</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then install the [Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter.java) in your `Moshi` instance:

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
    .add(Date.class, new Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter())
    .build();
```

It’ll give you dates as JSON strings in RFC 3339 format, like this: `"2017-05-06T20:00:00-05:00"`.

Comment: Any idea how to add this moshi instance to retrofit?

Comment: and what if the date isn't in Rfc3339 format? what if it looks like `2018-05-12T13:19:00Z` (ISO8601?)

Comment: RFC3339 supports dates that end with Z also. It is documented as a profile of ISO8601.

Comment: @PrashanD adding moshi to retrofit (kotlin):

`Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(Date::class.java, Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter()).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()))`


gradle dependencies:
`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.1'`